# Android - Reusing Activity with a different destination Activity in Intent() description

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm creating an Android exercise app -  I have 10 routines with around 4-5 exercises each. Each activity has one exercise featured on it with an activity `RestActivity` in-between.

I wish to have the rest activity appear after each exercise, where the user can click a button which moves the app forward to the next activity. So the activity flow would be 1,r,2,r,3 - like the image.

[image]

My problem is that the destination parameter in the Intent description will be different each time, so with 50-odd transitions between activities I believe it could get pretty messy. I also want to reuse RestActivity, as my college guide had the idea of creating copies RestActivity 50-odd times with the destination being the only change (I mean really?)

I had an idea of giving every activity a key and passing through an integer at each switch.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("key", 1); //Your id
intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
startActivity(intent);
```

I could use a wall of `if-elses` (or a `switch` statement) in `RestActivity` to work out the next `Activity` but I believe this would be rather messy.

Would anyone have any other ideas that would be of use?  Thanks again!

Comment: You probably want to use `Fragments` and/or `ViewPager`

Comment: Thank you v. much. I'll take a look into it.  I forgot to mention it's my first android app, but I'm getting there